# AWK: how to match a comma

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I want to return lines from awk with a pattern "C," or ".*,C" or ".*,C,.*".
For example:

#### Valid

```
C,G
G,C
G,C,A
```

#### Invalid

```
G,CC
```

My code is below:

```
 echo G,CC | awk '$0 ~ /^C,+.*|.*,C,*.*/ {print $0}'
```

### output:

```
G,CC
```

I hope it returns nothing to me. Unfortunately, it returns "G,CC" to me.

How do I solve this problem?

#### Edit:

Based on the answers from @Emma and @perreal. I used a shorter command line to solve my question:

```
awk '$0 ~ /^C,.*|.*,C,.*|.*,C$/ {print $0}'
```

Until now, it works well. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Perhaps rather than looking at the delimiters, focus on the data i.e. if it is not a single `C` it is invalid. `sed '/\bC\b/!d' file`.

Comment: The `.*`s in your final edit are doing nothing useful (`.*` means zero-or-more so then zero is an option), you could just remove them. Ditto for the `$0 ~` and the `{print $0}`. That would leave you with `awk '/^C,|,C,|,C$/'` which can be reduced to just https://stackoverflow.com/a/56923374/1745001.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that maybe this would also work:

```
awk '$0 ~ /^([A-Z],C,[A-Z]|[A-Z],C|C,[A-Z])$/ {print $0}'
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bpd6qi/1/)

#### Advice

[Mr. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin) is advising that:

> It is equivalent to `awk '/^([A-Z],C,[A-Z]|[A-Z],C|C,[A-Z])$/'`. Output
>   with print is the default operation along with the match against the
>   record.

Comment: It is equivalent to `awk '/^([A-Z],C,[A-Z]|[A-Z],C|C,[A-Z])$/'`. Output with `print` is the default operation along with the match against the complete record.

Answer (score 2):

- The `+` is not necessary in `^C,+.*`, since you already match the comma and also match whatever comes after.
- The `*` right after the second comma is not correct in `.*,C,*.*`. It makes the comma optional so it can also match `G,CC` (`.*,` matches `G,` and `C,*` matches `CC`).

This should work:

```
awk '$0 ~ /^[GCA](,[GCA])*$/ && /C/ {print $0}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your code. It works for "G,CC". But It cannot match "G,C". Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Updated the answer please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '!/CC/ && /^C,+.*|.*,C,*.*/'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/(^|,)C(,|$)/' file
C,G
G,C
G,C,A
```

Comment: well, that is short!

Answer (score 0):

## More alternatives

In other words, you want to select lines with "C" as word? If yes, here are 2 solutions:

```
grep -w C
grep -E '\<C\>'
```

The first one advises grep to match only whole words. The second line uses begin-word and end-word patterns. These pattern can be used with awk too:

```
awk '/\<C\>/ {print}'
```

A complete different solution (and different form other answers too) is to add commas at both ends before comparing `,C,`:

```
awk '"," $0 "," ~ /,C,/ {print}
```